# .Net Core JWT + cookie auth on Web API and MVC Web Project invalid signature

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core, jwt

My application first uses cookie auth to login. I then have it calling an API which I would like to use JWT auth which opens a websocket stream (Im debating and putting this stream on the UI) when the API gets an update it calls the UI and I want this one call to be a JWT Auth, I tried a bunch of things this past weekend but I keep getting invalid signature or SSL cert is invalid.

Both projects are .Net Core. One is a web api and the other is a MVC project
Its actually 2 APIS and MVC (userAPI, TraderAPI and the UI)

User API

```
         public string GenerateJWTToken(UserRoleVM user)
         {
             if (user != null)
             {
                 var secretKey = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(_config.GetSection("Tokens:Key").ToString());
                 var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretKey);
                 var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
                 var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                 var claims = new Claim[]
                 {
                      new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName)
                     ,new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sid, user.UserGUID)
                     ,new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, user.UserID.ToString())
                     ,new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email)
                     ,new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.AuthTime, currentTime.ToString())
                     ,new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role)
                     //,new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.)
                     ,new Claim(type: "Subscribed", value: user.IsSubscribed.ToString())
                     ,new Claim(type: "SubscribedDate", value: user.DateSubscribed.ToString())
    
                 };
    
                 var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken
                     (
                         signingCredentials: signingCredentials,
                         audience: _config.GetValue<string>("Tokens:Audience"),
                         issuer: _config.GetValue<string>("Tokens:Issuer"),
                         expires: currentTime.AddMinutes(_config.GetValue<int>("Tokens:LifeTime")),
                         //notBefore: currentTime,
                         claims: claims
                     );
                 return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);
             }
             return null;
         }
    
         //public Task<LoginResponseVM> Login(string username, string password)
         public async Task<string> Login(string username, string password)
         {
             string jwtToken = null;
             if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
             {
                 try
                 {
                     var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, false, false);
                     if (result.Succeeded)
                     {
                         //var savedUser = await _userService.GetUserByNameAsync(username);
                         //var role = await _userService.GetUserRolesAsync(savedUser);
                         var userVM = await _userService.GetUserNRole2Async(username);
                         //jwtToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GenerateJWTToken(userVM)));
                         jwtToken = GenerateJWTToken(userVM);
    
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
    
                 }
             }
             return jwtToken;
         }
    
 TraderAPI
  [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]        
         [HttpPost]
         //public async Task<IActionResult> GetTradeStatusUpdate([FromBody] TradeResultVM model)
         public async Task<IActionResult> SendTradeStatusUpdate([FromBody] TradeResultVM model)
         {
             _logger.LogInformation("Inside GetTradeStatus");
    
             var lstTradeStatuses = await GetLstTradeStatuses();
             if (lstTradeStatuses != null)
             {
                 await _semaphoreSlimS.WaitAsync();
                 try
                 {
                     foreach (var activeTrade in lstTradeStatuses)
                     {
                         if (activeTrade.TradeID == model.TradeID)
                         {
                             _logger.LogInformation("Trade found in lstTradeStatuses");
           ...
 }
    
         [HttpPost("SendUITradeStatusV4")]
         public async Task<IActionResult> SendUITradeStatusV4(BinanceStreamOrderUpdate orderUpdate, string token)
         {
             if (orderUpdate != null)
             {
                 TradeResultVM tradeVM = new TradeResultVM
                 {
                     //TradeName = "Test",
                     TradeID = orderUpdate.OrderId,
                     TradeSymbol = orderUpdate.Symbol,
                     Price = orderUpdate.Price,
                     Quantity = orderUpdate.Quantity                  
                 };
    
                 string trade = JsonSerializer.Serialize(tradeVM);//
                 using var client = _httpClient.CreateClient("TraderUI");
    
                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                 //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:50111");
                 //using var response = await client.PostAsync($"/HarkinsTrader/GetTradeStatusUpdate/",
                 _logger.LogInformation("Sending Key");
                 using var response = await client.PostAsync($"/HarkinsTrader/SendTradeStatusUpdate/",
                         new StringContent(trade, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                 {
                     _logger.LogInformation("Success StreamStatus Update");
                     return Ok();
                 }
             }
             return BadRequest();
         }
```

Comment: Did you install a ssl certificate correctly?Maybe you can try to reinstall it.

Comment: I'm using normal visual studio 2019. So localhost has the default cert